# Xcode 8.0 builds all targets after any change to code

Tags: xcode, xcode8

Xcode 8 will build every target in my project after any change I make to code. This doesn't happen after I relaunch Xcode though. It usually takes some time (20-60 minutes ish) of use before it begins to build all targets after every change.

What on earth is going on? It's very annoying and kills productivity. In Preferences>General I have 'Show live issues' & 'Continue building after errors' **unchecked**.

Thanks,
-justColbs

Comment: This seems like a recurring issue with Xcode 8. Have you tried the recent Xcode 8.2 beta?

Comment: @LeoNatan No I haven't. I'm hesitant to use new beta builds of Xcode because of the bad experience in the past. But it seems like every version of Xcode that Apple releases might as well be Beta, lol. Is it relatively stable ? And did it solve the issue for you ?

Comment: Yes, Apple software quality is very low in the last few years. I have not had this issue.

Comment: Also, open a bug report with Apple and post the number here so people can clone.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple known problems in Xcode 8.0 and 8.1 (technically possible before 8.0, but more likely in that release) which have been causing unnecessary full rebuilds for developers. These problems are now fixed in Xcode 8.2 beta 2. If you want to communicate with Apple about these issues, you can reference bug # 28892475. Please let us know if you still experience this issue in Xcode 8.2 beta 2 or a later release!

Comment: Thanks for the response Rick. I have downloaded Xcode 8.2 beta 1 and still have the same problem. it just builds all 3 targets over and over. Killing productivity. Hoping for fix in a coming release!

Comment: Thanks for letting us know that 8.2 beta 1 didn't fix this. I will update this thread when we do release a fix for the 2nd issue, 28892475; feel free to keep an eye out in our release notes for a mention of that bug as well.

Comment: Actually, your detail that "It usually takes some time (20-60 minutes ish) of use before it begins" is new to us. Can you please file a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com with details on your specific case so that we can make sure that 28892475 will address it?

Comment: Awesome thank you! Will do on the release notes. Regarding the timing of the issue, it is actually doing it 100% of the time now with zero delay after launching Xcode. I will still file a bug report if necessary.

Comment: A fix for this has been released in Xcode 8.2 beta 2. Please let us know if you still experience this problem with that beta!

Comment: Still same issue with Xcode 8.2 beta 2. I am not able to understand what does this mean:                                                                                        1.2ms <invalid loc> get {}
This is going in loops while compilation.